# Use CodeBehind instead of DLL

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I want to add new pages to a website without being have to recompile the whole site and copy the new dll to the bin folder.

I just want to upload the aspx files + the cs files.

Right now, when I try to do it the page won't load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with a Web Application Project, you have to compile and copy the dll and aspx files.

In your case you could also use a Web Site project. ASP.NET will compile your code while it's being accessed so you can only deploy new aspx and cs files.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) you can find an overview of the differences between Web Application Project and Web Site Project and also a few hints on when to choose which.